# Thin provisioning free space datastore

Tags: windows-server-2008, vmware-vsphere

If you have thin provisioning enabled and A C Drive says it 70GB of 200GB available. IS that 70GB part of the data store Free Space? Or is this allocated to that particular VM? Also If i delete the unnecessary files, will that increase the amount of free space in the data store in the Vsphere client.

Answer (score 0):

Thin provisioning allows the .vmdk file to "grow" as needed with data. It will not shrink if you delete files. The purpose of thin provisioning is to make them easier to back up since they're smaller, plus quicker to create.

The free space is reported by vSphere as how much is allocated to the VM. The free datastore space is what's currently not allocated to any VM.